# How to use gnu awk for windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, awk

I am not sure if this is the right place for this question but since I am trying to write a batch file and gnu awk is giving me problems, I thought I'd ask it here.

My purpose is quite simple. I'd like to keep track of PIDs of windows processes in files. For instance I want to push the PIDs of putty.exe processes into a file called putty.pid, with the following command:

```
tasklist | find "putty.exe" | awk '{print $2}' > putty.pid
```

and this is what I am getting on my dos window

```
C:\MyUtil>tasklist | find "putty" | awk '{print $2}' > putty.pid
awk: '{print
awk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression
```

can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here ? 
I freshly downloaded awk from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm

and extracted one single file awk.exe into my current directory. I might be missing a dll or something but its documentation is not very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows, the script you pass in command line to `awk` must be enclosed in double quotes, the same quoting you are using in the string you pass to `find`.

Comment: Thank you... I am in your debt :) But isn't it stupid that all the examples and everything in the downloaded package showing single quotes, as it is in unix platform.